# Activate Unit Test in Development and Test Phase and not Production phase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Goal:
Unit testing method TestMethod1 can only be used in development and test phase.
If it being used in production phase, everything will be canceled or similar.

Problem:
When I tried removing the string value "Development" from useEnvironment() method, the code is still working.

Is it possbile to activate the unit testing  in development and test phase and not in production phase?

Info:
*Source code is taken from https://www.meziantou.net/testing-an-asp-net-core-application-using-testserver.htm
*Please take account that you might have about 500 unit test.
*Using asp.net core mvc v3

Thank you!

---

```
------

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xunit;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Testtest;

namespace XUnitTestProject1.Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://www.meziantou.net/testing-an-asp-net-core-application-using-testserver.htm
    /// </summary>
    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            var webHostBuilder =
                  new WebHostBuilder()
                        .UseEnvironment("Development") // You can set the environment you want (development, staging, production)
                        .UseStartup<Startup>(); // Startup class of your web app project

            using (var server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder))
            using (var client = server.CreateClient())
            {
                string result = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/values");
                Assert.Equal("[\"value1\",\"value2\"]", result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testtest.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ValuesController
    /// </summary>
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

---

Updated:

[image]

```
[CustomTestsFact]
[Fact]
public async Task TestMethod2()
{
    using (var client = _server.CreateClient())
    {
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/values");
        Assert.Equal("[\"value1\",\"value2\"]", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XUnit **FactAttribute** has **Skip** property that can be used to skip method.

You can create a custom class that will derive from **FactAttribute** and use your env variable to control whether the method should be skipped:

```
    public class CustomFactAttribute : FactAttribute
      {
    public CustomTestsFactAttribute()
    {
        var phaseVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("name of your env variable");
        
        Skip = phaseVariable == "production"
            ? "Tests ignored"
            : base.Skip;
    }
}
```

And then you can mark your method with CustomFactAttribute:

```
   [CustomTestsFact]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
       //your logic
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work

Comment: Could you show the code, and what do you mean by it doesn't work, did you try to debug the solution?

Comment: @What'sUP well you can't __compile__ a solution from @Buhhovsky. It is not the same as _it does not work_. The reason is obvious - there are no `CustomTestsFactAttribute` in your test project (according to the error you have shown). Have you forgot to copy-paste the `CustomTestsFactAttribute` class defition? Also please note that this solution depends on environment variable so you can't just copy-paste, you have to use variable name in `GetEnvironmentVariable` call (and set this variable value before test are being executed)